# Java Syntax Error: The method Foo is undefined for the type Bar

Tags: java, generics

I found this in a java book and would like to understand why am I getting the error as outlined below:

```
public class Wildcard<V> {

    V value;

    public Wildcard(V value) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
    }

    public V getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(V value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public boolean sameObj(Wildcard<? extends V> v1, MyComparator<V> comparator) {
        return comparator.compare(this.value, v1.value);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Wildcard<Integer> iTest = new Wildcard<Integer>(10);
        Wildcard<Number> nTest = new Wildcard<Number>(10);
        nTest.sameObject(iTest, new MyComparator<Number>() {
            public boolean compare(Number o1, Number o2) {
                return o1 == o2;
            }
        });
    }
}

interface MyComparator<V> {
    public boolean compare (V value,V value2) ;
}
```

The syntax error that appears on the line `nTest.sameObject` is:

`The method sameObject(Wildcard<Integer>, new MyComparator<Number>(){}) is undefined for the type Wildcard<Number>`

Since the method is being called on class `Wildcard` parameterized with `Number`, the first parameter to `sameObject` function can be anything that extends `V` (Number in this case) and the parameter to the function that appears next should be `V` (a Number in this case). Hence it should be a legal call. Why is it not a legal call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely a typo. `sameObj` != `sameObject`.

Comment: Good catch, that was hard to see.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As `col6y` pointed out, you should rename the `sameObj` method to `sameObject`.

As further improvement, I suggest that you change the method's signature as follows

```java
public boolean sameObject(Wildcard<? extends V> v1, MyComparator<? super V> comparator)
```

It then follows the **PECS** (producer extends, consumer super) rule. This enables you, in that specific case, to invoke the method `sameObject` with a comparator that was designed for a super type of `V`.

For more information on PECS you can read Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, or take a quick look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs) on SO.